# Intellij idea freeze at startup, fsnotifier64 uses 6.5G RAM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, out-of-memory, freeze, intellij-14

I'm using fedora 21, when I launch Intellij it freezes my mouse and keyboard at about 75%, but somehow it continues to load while frozen input. When it fineshed i was happy, but now my fsnotifier64 process uses 6.5GB of RAM. I have changed my vmoptions, which doesn't change anything. What would you suggest me to try to fix this issue.

Comment: Just guessing - does your project directory contain a huge number of files? (try running `find /project/dir | wc -l`)

Comment: I have same issue with Xubuntu

Comment: Here's the log. I hope intellij guys will fix this. http://pastebin.com/hMCaHN8D

Comment: Similar problem here with PhpStorm 10, except it's not 75% but 400% (100% on all 4 cores), and also happens when closing the IDE.